# print a configurationmanager.appsettings variable on an aspx page?

Tags: asp.net

I can't seem to print a configurationmanager.appsettings variable to an aspx page.  So in my index.aspx file, I have the following line of code:

```
<%# (string) ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myvariable"] %>
```

But nothing prints out.

However, if I add an `asp:textbox` to the `index.aspx` page, then bind the variable to it from the `index.aspx.cs` page like so:

```
textbox.Text = (string) ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myvariable"];
```

Then it shows up.

How do i print a configuration variable directly to index.aspx without the code behind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<%#` is a data binding expression, it evaluates only if you perform a data binding. if no, nothing will be be rendered. you should use a `<%=` construct instead:

```
<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myvariable"] %>
```

or you could use even a shorter `<%$` construct here e.g.:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ appSettings:myvariable%>" />
```